# Would be ,Will be

Tags: subjunctives

> It **would** be very helpful to me for my presentation tomorrow.

or

> It **will** be very helpful to me for my presentation tomorrow.

Which one is grammatically correct? Which is most suitable ?

Please explain.

Answer (score 1):

Both the sentences are grammatical.

You can use either will or would to talk about the future, but there's a little difference in meaning.

In the first sentence with the use of would, you are expressing that there's a possibility of it being helpful to you, whereas in the second sentence with the use of will, you are positive or sure of it being helpful to you.

If you are sure that it will be helpful, use the will.

If you are not sure (you think it may be helpful or may not be helpful) use the would.